# WPF - Dependency Property of Custom Control lost Binding at 2 way mode

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have this Custom Control

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UC"
             ...
             x:Name="uc">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Test, ElementName=uc}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```
public partial class UC : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty;

    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TestProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static UC()
    {
        TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Test",typeof(string),
                      typeof(UC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    }

    public UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And this is how i used that custom control:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataList}"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <local:UC Test="{Binding SelectedString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

--

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _dataList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> DataList
    {
        get { return _dataList; }
        set
        {
            _dataList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataList");
        }
    }

    private string _selectedString;
    public string SelectedString
    {
        get { return _selectedString; }
        set
        {
            _selectedString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedString");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.DataList.Add("1111");
        this.DataList.Add("2222");
        this.DataList.Add("3333");
        this.DataList.Add("4444");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedString = (sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I do not change text of `UC`, everything is ok. When I click each button in the left panel, button's content is displayed on `UC`.

But when I change text of `UC` (ex: to 9999), `Test` property lost binding. When I click each button in the left panel, text of `UC` is the same that was changed (9999). In debug I see that `SelectedString` is changed by each button click but UC's text is not.

I can 'fix' this problem by using this `<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, ElementName=uc, Mode=OneWay}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>` in the `UC`.

But I just want to understand the problem, can someone help me to explain it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the value of the target of a OneWay binding clears the binding. The binding `<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, ElementName=uc}"` is two way, and when the text changes it updates the Test property as well. But the Test property is the Target of a OneWay binding, and that binding is cleared.

Your 'fix' works because as a OneWay binding, it never updates Test and the binding is never cleared. Depending on what you want, you could also change the UC binding to `<local:UC Test="{Binding SelectedString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` Two Way bindings are not cleared when the source or target is updated through another method.

Comment: I love this "Setting the value of the target of a OneWay binding clears the binding." - thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with below line

```
 <local:UC Test="{Binding SelectedString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The mode is set as oneway for `SelectString` binding so text will be updated when the value from code base changes. To change either the source property or the target property to automatically update the binding source as `TwoWay`.

```
   <local:UC Test="{Binding SelectedString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: =.= thank you but please read the Original Poster again please